# PostgreSQL replication streaming stopped in aws rds

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

We have PostgreSQL RDS instance in AWS and a read replica of this instance is available . Streaming of replication stopped at a point of time .
Which may be the reasons behind this ?

Comment: 1. Check if postgresql service is in running state on both instances.
2. Check if both instances can connect to each other using psql.

Comment: @vipin_devops I'm seeing the same thing starting Feb 7th (after having been using Postgres on RDS for years on this project without a hiccup).  Both instances are active.  No idea what's wrong.